# Toggle event.preventDefault based on classname

Tags: javascript, jquery, preventdefault

I want to toggle the `preventDefault` method based on the classname of the link element.

**Example:**

```
<a href="#" class="myLink disabled">My link</a>

//TO-DO: enable click only when link doesn't have disabled class
$('.myLink').on('click', function() {
    //DO SOME STUFF
});
```

Comment: _"toggle the preventdefault"_ ? What ?

Comment: `$('.myLink').on('click', function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
});` ...?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can bind the event on the element which don't have a particular class. Using `:not()` selector, elements can be excluded.

```
$('.myLink:not(.disabled)').on('click', function
```

If the `disabled` class is applied dynamically, you have to check if the clicked link have that class using [`hasClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/).

```
$('.myLink').on('click', function(event) {
    if ($(this).hasClass('disabled')) {
        event.preventDefault();

        // return false; // Use when no action should be performed
    } else {
        // Handle event
        ...
    }
});
```

Comment: is `return false === event.preventDefault();` ?

Comment: @AndrewEvt `return false; === e.preventDefault(); + e.stopPropagation();`

Comment: @Tushar, Will `return false;` prevent bubbling of event with `on` event binding ? Just a doubt!

Comment: @Tushar the link is more on `return false` there is no mention of *prevent bubbling of event with on event binding* i want to know about this as well :)

Comment: @Tushar, That was cool! Something new for me:P ...Thanks mate!

Comment: @guradio, Some snack for you https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/hqeo0fvy/ ... Also consider the comment under the accepted answer by great _T.J. Crowder_

Comment: @guradio Quoting from same link _`e.preventDefault()` will prevent the default event from occuring, `e.stopPropagation()` will prevent the event from bubbling up and **`return false` will do both**. Note that this behaviour differs from normal (non-jQuery) event handlers, in which, notably, return false does not stop the event from bubbling up._

Comment: @RayonDabre that was clearer sorry english is not my first language seeing the sample helps understand better :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(".myLink:not(.disabled)").on('click', function() {
    //DO SOME STUFF
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<a href="#" class="myLink disabled">My link</a>

//TO-DO: enable click only when link doesn't have disabled class
$('.myLink').on('click', function(e) {
    if ($(this).hasClass('disabled') {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
    // do thomething
});
```